# Controlling the width of a Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know how to set the width of the InfoWindow in Google Maps? The infowindow is the cartoon like bubble that pops up when you click on a point in Google Maps. I can control the height via CSS but cannot figure out how to change the width (I want thinner than the default infowindow).

I found a reference to maxWidth in the API but I cannot figure out where to put this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For v3 of the API, the `InfoWindowOptions.maxWidth` property does what you're asking for. The `InfoWindow` constructor takes an optional argument of an `InfoWindowOptions` object.

```
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: some_text, maxWidth: 200 });
```

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) notes that the *"value is only considered if it is set before a call to open. To change the maximum width when changing content, call close, setOptions, and then open."*

Comment: It's worth noting that maxWidth won't let you shrink the width beyond a certain point--around 200px I believe, which is pretty wide for many purposes.

Comment: This does not work. I suggest going with the css override seen lower.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the style override, and see that it works, but testing the solution described above just now shows that it is still working for me, and I can control the infoWindow width. Page I tested was XHTML 1.0 Strict, but going to HTML5 works equally well.

Answer (score 17):

You can override the style of Google Maps.

```
/* Just use .gm-style-iw */ 
.gm-style-iw {
  width: 300px; 
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Source: https://katz.co/resizing-infowindow/

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot an issue that was apparently introduced with Google Maps v3: the width of the infoMarker had been auto-figured before, but just recently I noticed it was overflowing in my app (since v3). Specifying a narrower width for .gm-style-iw fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: *oh and also, for me, I had to add "!important" to the width in the CSS in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can add div at first like this:

```
<div style='width:300px;margin:0 0 20px 20px;height:90px;'>
```