# Google maps set width for InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am using InfoWindow to get custom popup on google maps,
but I can't set it width, I tried setting it inline to wrapper tag, but it doesn't work.
In this case I need it to be 750px.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxast/
and here is html file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?66dbe6xzn1mul10

Here is method that is setting InfoWindow content:

```
 function getContent(parts, kmlEvent) {

                var content = ""+
       "<div id='width800' class='google-infobox-content' >" +
            "<div class='image'>" +
                "<img src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + kmlEvent.latLng.Ya + "," + kmlEvent.latLng.Za + "&amp;zoom=13&amp;size=150x150&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;sensor=false&amp;language=&amp;markers=color:red|label:none|48.7758013,9.2529132' title='' width='150' height='150' >" +
                "<br />" +
                "<a href='https://maps.google.com/maps?sensore=true&daddr=" + kmlEvent.latLng.Za + "," + kmlEvent.latLng.Ya + "' target='_blank' >Full Google Map</a>" +
                "<a href='http://maps.google.com/help/maps/directions/Somewhere' target='_blank' >Directions</a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='location'>" +
                "<p>" + parts[0] + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + parts[1] + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + parts[2] + "</p>" +
                "<br/>" +
                "<p>" + parts[3] + "</p>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='contact'>" +
                "<p>" + parts[4] + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + parts[5] + "</p>" +
                "<a href='mailto:" + parts[6] + "' >" + parts[6] + "</a>" +
                "<a href='" + parts[7] + "' target='_blank' >" + parts[7] + "</a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='others'>" +
                "<p><b>Product line</b></p>" +
                "<p>" + parts[8] + 
                "</p>" +
            "</div>" +                
        "</div>";

                return content;
            }​
```

**Updated**
here is updated jsfiddle with setted maxWidth and inline width for wrapper tag, but still it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/xxast/3/

Comment: how did you try to set it's width to 750px?  I would have expected to see a style='width:750px;' applied to the outer div, I don't see that.

Comment: I remove inline style when saw that it doesn't work.

Comment: @jasin_89: got some information for you. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In infoWinfow options try to set maxWidth to 750. Also to make sure the style is not overwiten by default goole values rename google-infobox-content to something different. You may try to use a custom info window library:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

Comment: In provided jsfiddle I already sett it to 800, and class 'google-infobox-content' is mine :)

Comment: It seems to me Google info window has limited width (690 pixeles). If nothing works follow the above link

Comment: Pleast to confirm the infoBubble is able to create info windows even widder than 750px, so good luck!

Answer (score 10):

there is no `width` in the [google.maps.InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) object.

create a `div` inside your infowindow, and set its width.
the infowindow will resize to fit the internal `div`.

i have a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

### EDIT

some extra info:

i've found [in a google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/G0pHpaeqK7o) a very interesting information, [written by a google employee](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/G0pHpaeqK7o/V4GBDa6cuuEJ).

> Info window size is determined based on two factors:
>
> - the size of the content
> - the size of the map (not the browser)

to be free of this, you must implement your own kind of infowindow.

some examples here:

- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html
- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html

Comment: in your example I couldn't find any marker to click, but what is wrong  in mine example.

Comment: sorry about that, yes in your example it is working now comparing it with mine I don't know what is wrong in mine code....

Comment: last column for me needs to be wider and see it in firefox

Answer (score 3):

Google v3 Api comes with:

```
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: some_text, maxWidth: 200 });
```

More details here : [Controlling the width of a Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844314/controlling-the-width-of-a-google-maps-infowindow)

Answer (score 1):

```
  Use as below in your google map script

  //content = anything you like to show
  var content = '<div id="content" align="center">'+          
              '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="margin:0;color:#ff6600;">Your Title</h1>'+ 
              '<p style="color:#0d6585;font-weight:700;">Your Description'+
              '</p>'+
              '</div>';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: content,
     maxWidth: 300 //your desired width
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `div` and set that to the infowindow using `setcontent` it works for sure