# Google earth plugin - Balloon appears 'cut'

Tags: mapping, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

When I load a my KML in google earth, the balloon pops up fine (showing the close button) but when I embed it in  a web page, it appears cut. What could be the problem?  How do I solve that?

I have posted an image on how it appears on the html page[image: Appearance of the balloon on the webpage]

Answer (score 0):

You can have some control over the InfoWindow size, but it is also based on the map size. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13292088/1803682

Also note the link in the accepted answer to the google maps utility InfoBubble which can be bigger: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html